# iPhone: How to do kCATransitionMoveIn without the fade effect

Tags: iphone, animation, transition

I am doing a transition of views with type as kCATransitionMoveIn and subtype as kCATransitionFromRight.

This works fine with the new view fading in as it comes from right and old view fading out. Can the fading be avoided ? I would like to have the view coming in with the alpha of 1, and the outgoing view to be seen clearly until it is until it is fully replaced. Is this possible & how to do this ?

Answer (score 0):

yes, its possible, u can do it by moving them manually , using the [UIView beginAnimation] method, just chain a couple of animation and u're good to go